# Retrieving rows with a specific string format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in SQL Server that contains 'FIRST NAME', 'LAST NAME', 'MD' or
'FIRST NAME' 'MI' 'LAST NAME', 'MD' or a column with a name of a company. I would like to run a query where it looks for rows with this exact format 'string','sting','MD' and omits the other formats.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If these are comma separated, then this LIKE statement does what you are looking for:

`WHERE Column LIKE '[A-Z]%,[A-Z]%,MD'`

If it is space delimited, then try this:

`WHERE Column LIKE '[A-Z]%[ ][A-Z]%[ ]MD'`